# How can I erase a string on the screen before moving to the next line?

Tags: c++

So my code below removes all the numbers from a string. and each time it removes a number it goes to the next line. I want the previous lines to disappear after displaying it. I tried using system("clear") in my if loop but it did not work. how would I do this?

```
string sentence;

cout<<"Enter sentence: "<<endl;

cin.ignore();

getline(cin,sentence);

for(int i=0;i<sentence.length();i++) {

    if(isdigit(sentence[i]))
    
    {
        sentence.erase(i, 1);
        i--;
        cout<<sentence;
        cout<<endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using flush: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush

Comment: If your terminal emulates VT (most do), you can use the ANSI escape `\033[2K` to erase the current line.

Answer (score 2):

Not a standard way to do this. But you imply Unix in your question, so this might work: use std::flush and backspaces to erase a line.

It mostly worked for me when I tried it out on Linux:

```
    cout<<sentence << std::flush;
    sleep(1);
    string backspaces;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sentence.size(); i++) {
        backspaces += '\b';
    }
    cout << backspaces << std::flush;
```

However, if the subsequent line is shorter than the previous line, some residual chars would remain. Might need to pad with spaces too.

You may want to investigate using the [termios](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) functions as well to see if any of that will help you.

Other options to explore include ANSI escape sequences or [NCurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: It won’t actually work that way: once the _user_ presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> then the cursor is already on the next line.

Comment: Look at the library links I suggested and google for "raw input".

Answer (score 0):

Once the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> the cursor is already on the wrong line.

Fortunately, both Linux terminal emulators and the modern Windows Terminal should accept `Esc` `[` `A` to move the cursor up one line. Then you can emit a carriage return to move to the beginning of the line and print out enough spaces to clear — or you could just use the clear-line code: `Esc` `[` `K`.

```
void cursor_up()  { std::cout << "\033[A"; }
void clear_line() { std::cout << "\033[K"; }
```

Neither terminal should need any magic setup to work for those two [Virtual Terminal sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences).

Edit to add [Thomas E Dickey’s fabulous reference](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) as well.

Comment: `0K` just clears to end-of-line, `2K` clears the entire line. Not sure which is needed.

Comment: Since newline puts cursor at the front of the line, you only need to clear to EOL once you move up. (So both are correct.)

Comment: Makes sense. `0K` clears whole line in that case `:)`